# Loopback 4: Defining property in model as array

Tags: typescript, loopbackjs, v4l2loopback

I have a user model with a property addresses:

```
@property.array(Address)
addresses: Array<Address>;
```

But I get an error:

```
Cannot start the application. Error: "items" property must be present if "type" is an array
```

According to Loopback [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Model.html), I do not need to do anything else.

Any idea what is missing?

Answer (score 4):

We usually don't declare arrays with Array type. The below code works for us. Try it out.

```
@property.array(Address)
addresses?: Address[];
```

Comment: @eduardo, if this answer worked for you, can you please accept this answer ?

Comment: this has stopped working now after I updated the codebase to latest published versions of LB4

Answer (score 2):

Loopback 4 (lb4)-

I had a requirement of creating a model property which would be an array of array. I tried to generate this property using lb4 CLI but I was not prompted for an `array` item type so I chose `any`.

The generated code was something like this-

```
@property({
  type: 'array',
  itemType: 'any'
})
extraInfo?: any[];
```

Comment: using "itemType" worked for me with Loopback v4.0.7